# jQuery Form Validation - Don't Scroll to Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have the following function when a user is submitting a form

```
if ( $('form').checkValidity() ) {
   // send the form
} else {
  // do stuff with the errors
}
```

The page scrolls to any input fields which have errors.

How can I stop the page scrolling?

I have tried

```
$('form').checkValidity({focusInvalid: false})
```

but to no effect.

Comment: what library are you using for form validation, if any?

Comment: Webshim http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/forms.html

Comment: I imageine you either need to set an option or 2 ex `webshim.setOptions('extendNative', true);` or most likely prevent the default action. I am not sure if it is HTML5 scrolling to the errors or jQuery from the library. I imagine it is HTML5 so you will need to prevent that action from happening. I have never used this library, sorry I am not of more help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this - or you could always use a different library for form validation:

```
webshim.setOptions("forms", {
    list: {
        "filter": "*",
        "multiple": false,
        "focus": false, // perhaps this is what you need to set
        "highlight": false,
        "valueCompletion": false,
        "inlineValue": false,
        "noHtmlEscape": false,
        "popover": {
            "constrainWidth": true
        }
    }
});
```

Or maybe this:

```
webshim.setOptions("forms", {
    iVal: {
        "sel": ".ws-validate",
        "handleBubble": "hide",
        "recheckDelay": 400,
        "fieldWrapper": ":not(span):not(label):not(em):not(strong):not(p)",
        "events": "focusout change",
        "errorClass": "user-error",
        "errorWrapperClass": "ws-invalid",
        "successWrapperClass": "ws-success",
        "errorBoxClass": "ws-errorbox",
        "errorMessageClass": "ws-errormessage",
        "fx": "slide", // fx?? maybe none here - again i am not familiar with this lib
        "submitCheck": false
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('form').checkValidity(focusInvalid: false)
```

Will give you a syntax error.

Try

```
$('form').checkValidity({focusInvalid: false})
```